# Is .data still useful in pytorch?

Tags: python, version, pytorch, tensor

I'm new to pytorch. I read much pytorch code which heavily uses tensor's `.data` member. But I search `.data` in the official document and Google, finding little. I guess `.data` contains the data in the tensor, but I don't know when we need it and when not?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`.data` was an attribute of `Variable` (object representing `Tensor` with history tracking e.g. for automatic update), not `Tensor`. Actually, `.data` was giving access to the `Variable`'s underlying `Tensor`.

However, since PyTorch version `0.4.0`, `Variable` and `Tensor` have been merged (into an updated `Tensor` structure), so `.data` disappeared along the previous `Variable` object (well `Variable` is still there for backward-compatibility, but is deprecated).

---

Paragraph from [Release Notes](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.0) for version `0.4.0` (I recommend reading the whole section about `Variable`/`Tensor` updates):

> **What about `.data`?**
>
> `.data` was the primary way to get the underlying `Tensor` from a
>   `Variable`. After this merge, calling `y = x.data` still has similar
>   semantics. So `y` will be a `Tensor` that shares the same data with
>   `x`, is unrelated with the computation history of `x`, and has
>   `requires_grad=False`.
>
> However, `.data` can be unsafe in some cases. Any changes on `x.data`
>   wouldn't be tracked by `autograd`, and the computed gradients would be
>   incorrect if `x` is needed in a backward pass. A safer alternative is
>   to use `x.detach()`, which also returns a `Tensor` that shares data
>   with `requires_grad=False`, but will have its in-place changes
>   reported by `autograd` if `x` is needed in backward.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it safe to use it in PixelCNN https://github.com/axeloh/pixelcnn-pytorch/blob/master/masked_cnn_layer.py#L17

Answer (score 3):

Aside from @benjaminplanche 's answer, I'd use it to manually change values of parameters.

For instance, I have the following model:

```
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10, 1))
```

and for some reason, I'd like to manually update the values of its parameters. Then, I can do:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.data = 10 * param.data  # multiply the parameter values by 10.
```

Note that if we remove `.data` behind `param`, the parameter values won't be updated.

Such use can be found in [BYOL (Bootstrap your own latent)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.07733) and [this Github webpage for BYOL pytorch implementation](https://github.com/lucidrains/byol-pytorch/blob/2aa84ee18fafecaf35637da4657f92619e83876d/byol_pytorch/byol_pytorch.py#L61).

Comment: I just tried this and while you need `.data` on the left-hand-side, you don't need the `.data` on the right-hand-side. Pytorch 1.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

From PyTorch 0.4.0 and at least version 1.7.1 - you can take torch.Tensor content via this attributed ".data".

Assume you have `point=torch.Tensor(size=(1,2,)); point.requires_grad_(True);`

In that case:

1. `point.data` will be a Tensor that shares the same data with `point`.

You can check it with: `point.data_ptr(); point.data.data_ptr();`

2. it's is unrelated to the computation history of `point.data`, has `requires_grad=False` even `point` has `requires_grad=True`
3. Any changes on initial_point.data wouldn't be tracked by autograd

**Documentation**:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.0