# What is the meaning of keep_vars in state_dict?

Tags: pytorch

`state_dict(destination=None, prefix='', keep_vars=False)`

what does changing `keep_vars` to `True` do?

Answer (score 1):

In PyTorch >=0.4, it has no use.

`keep_vars` was added in the commit: [Add keep_vars parameter to state_dict](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/63c835bbe7eaad6ad564ebd6df88e8e35dd2d6d9) stating that

> When keep_vars is true, it returns a Variable for each parameter
>           (rather than a Tensor).

In `state_dict` function, [`_save_to_state_dict`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L658) is called internally, which contains the following code

```py
for name, param in self._parameters.items():
            if param is not None:
                destination[prefix + name] = param if keep_vars else param.data
        for name, buf in self._buffers.items():
            if buf is not None:
                destination[prefix + name] = buf if keep_vars else buf.data
```

The portion `param if keep_vars else param.data` made difference prior to PyTorch 0.4.0 when `Variable` and `Tensor` were separate, but now as they are merged, `keep_vars` is probably present only for backward compatibility. Check [Is .data still useful in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51743214/6210807)