# Is .data still useful in pytorch 1.3 stable and what is the meaning of it?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Is .data still be used in the pytorch 1.3 stable, if so, could you please share the reference to me? Thx.

```py
t = torch.randperm(8)
t.data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is .data still useful in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743214/is-data-still-useful-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PyTorch v0.4.0, calling `y = x.data` still has similar semantics. So `y` will be a Tensor that shares the same data with `x`, is unrelated to the computation history of `x`, and has `requires_grad=False`.

However, `.data` can be unsafe in some cases. Any changes on `x.data` wouldn't be tracked by autograd, and the computed gradients would be incorrect if `x` is needed in a backward pass. A safer alternative is to use `x.detach()`, which also returns a Tensor that shares data with `requires_grad=False`, but will have its in-place changes reported by autograd if `x` is needed in backward.

Reference: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.0