# Difference between .detach() and .data.detach() in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

What is the difference between `.detach()` and `.data.detach()` in PyTorch?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51744091/7615877) may be useful. Basically, `.data` was part of `Variable` which has been deprecated since PyTorch 0.4.0. So, both should ideally give the same results (AFAIK), but it is recommended to not use `.data` (it only provides backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

"You should always use .detach() if you want to detach a tensor from the graph. The other option .data is for older versions of PyTorch, and it is likely that it will be removed from the future versions of PyTorch." from https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-difference-between-data-and-detach/30926

Answer (score 0):

while both .detach() and .data.detach() can be used to detach tensors from the computation graph, .detach() is a safer and more recommended way to achieve this, as it creates a new tensor that is explicitly detached. Using .data.detach() should be done with caution, as it gives you direct access to the tensor's data and can lead to unintended consequences, especially in cases where gradient computations are involved.