# What does output.data mean in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

The code below appears [in this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html).

```
total = 0
# since we're not training, we don't need to calculate the gradients for our outputs
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images, labels = data
        # calculate outputs by running images through the network
        outputs = net(images)
        # the class with the highest energy is what we choose as prediction
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += labels.size(0)
        correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

print('Accuracy of the network on the 10000 test images: %d %%' % (
    100 * correct / total))
```

Why do you write `outputs.data` here?
I want to know the difference from using `outputs` only.

Comment: maybe first use `print(output)` and `print(output.data)` to see difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; **`Tensor` and `Tensor.data` are not the same!** Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67716853/6331369).

While [`Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html) and `Tensor.data` do share the same memory they are not the same interface to accessing it. Also, notice how `Tensor.data` *is* a `Tensor`, which means the `data` attribute is recursive... However, there is a difference between the two: operations performed on the data attribute will bypass Autograd's check. This means any computation performed from `Tensor.data` won't be tracked for backpropagation. In practice, this means that using `data` for computing is identical to detaching the tensor from its computational graph *if any*.