# Accuracy value more than 1 with nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() loss function pytorch in Binary Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function, transfer-learning

I am trying to use `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()` for model which [initially](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html) used `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. However, after doing some changes to the training function to accommodate the `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()` loss function the model accuracy values are shown as more than 1. Please find the code below.

```
# Data augmentation and normalization for training
# Just normalization for validation
data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

data_dir = '/kaggle/input/catsndogsorg/hymenoptera_data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

#############

def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}')
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device).unsqueeze(1)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    #print(outputs, labels)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels.float())
                    print(loss)
                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print(f'{phase} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f} Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}')

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print(f'Training complete in {time_elapsed // 60:.0f}m {time_elapsed % 60:.0f}s')
    print(f'Best val Acc: {best_acc:4f}')

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model
```

EDIT:Model pipeline

```
model_ft = models.resnet18(weights='ResNet18_Weights.DEFAULT')
num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
# Here the size of each output sample is set to 2.
# Alternatively, it can be generalized to nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_names)).
model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 1)

model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

# Observe that all parameters are being optimized
optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

model_ft = train_model(model_ft, criterion, optimizer_ft, 
     exp_lr_scheduler,num_epochs=25)
```

The outputs of training loop:

```
outputs shape:  torch.Size([4, 1])
labels shape:  torch.Size([4, 1])

logits: tensor(0.3511,grad_fn<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward0>)

train Loss: 1.0000 Acc: 2.0164
val Loss: 1.0000 Acc: 1.8105
```

Would anyone be able to help me in this matter please.

Thanks & Best Regards
AMJS

Comment: Are you doing multi-class or multi-label classification?

Comment: Hi, Binary classification please Thanks

Comment: Can you make sure that `preds` and `labels` have the same shapes?

Comment: I am concerned about the `output` variable. `output` variable is supposed to have the same shape as the `label`. But in this case, the `output` shape is [4, 2], and the shape of the `label` is [4, 1] if the batch size is 4.

Comment: Possibly `dataset_sizes` is incorrect. You could try doing your own counting in each phase loop to make sure you have the correct number of items. And in any case you are not guaranteed to use every item in the dataset on every epoch depending on the dataloader batching settings

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Both `outputs` variable and `labels` variable have the same shape. Thanks

Comment: @AlainMichaelJanithSchroter You didn't include crucial pieces of your code, namely the places where the `dataloaders` and `dataset_sizes` dicts are computed. BTW, why are you comparing against `labels.data`? That's [deprecated since PyTorch 0.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743214/is-data-still-useful-in-pytorch#51744091)

Comment: Hi, I got the code from here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html. Included the code parts that I changed only in this question. Changed the loss function to nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss() from nn.CrossEntropyLoss(). Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: Check the variable `image_datasets`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't understand why you are using `torch.max` as you have one output. Anyway, you should use squeeze before comparing, so this line:

```
running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
```

should become

```
 running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.squeeze())
```

to see why:

```
labels = torch.tensor([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [1]])

preds = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 0])
print(torch.sum(preds == labels)) # output 12
print(torch.sum(preds == labels.squeeze())) # output 3
```

Comment: I agree with @coder00. As you are using binary classification, you can use the sigmoid, and a threshold to distinguish between positive or negative labels.

Comment: Also note that if you're using sigmoid, with the current shape of your code, you will not need the `squeeze()` call on the labels if I'm not mistaken